# Port Channel issue on Cisco gear

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus, vpc, ios-xe

I have a lab where I'm connecting a Cisco CSR1000V and a Nexus 9000 switch. These devices are connected back to back. Relevant configuration is:

Router:

```
interface Port-channel1
mtu 9216
!
interface Port-channel1.1000
encapsulation dot1Q 1000
 ip address 10.1.1.2 255.255.255.128
vrrp 1 ip 10.1.1.1
vrrp 1 priority 150
vrrp 1 track 1 decrement 70
!
interface GigabitEthernet2
mtu 9216
no ip address
speed 1000
channel-group 1
!
```

Nexus 9K:

```
interface Vlan1000
ip address 10.1.1.4/25
!
interface port-channel1
switchport mode trunk
mtu 2916
spanning-tree port type normal
!
ip route 0.0.0.0/0 10.1.1.1
!
interface Ethernet1/1
switchport mode trunk
mtu 2916
channel-group 1
!
```

Connection is between router G2 and Nexus E1/1. Problem is, they can't talk to each other. The Router is master in vrrp status. Interfaces look good:

[image: Router]

Port Channel 1:

[image: Router Port channel 1]

The Nexus switch shows the same interface status:

E1/1:

[image: Nexus E1/1]

Port Channel 1:

[image: Nexus po1]

So, all looks up but can't ping switch from router:

```
CSR-2.rt#ping 10.1.1.4
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 10.1.1.4, timeout is 2 seconds:
.....
Success rate is 0 percent (0/5)
```

At this point I can't tell if the issue is on the CSR or in the Nexus switch. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please, never use images for text. Simply copy the text and paste it into the question using the Preformatted-text option (`{}`). Also, you cannot connect a layer-3 port channel to a layer-2 port channel, and VRRP is pointless with a single router.

Comment: Have you created VLAN 1000 on the Nexus? Type *show spanning-tree vlan 1000*

Comment: I'd start by correcting your interface-to-port-channel configurations.  Your screenshots indicate each side of the port-channel has two members, but your config pastes show only one.  Additionally, your CSR1000V side has traffic but N9K has no traffic.  Without knowing more, we cannot rule out a cabling mistake.  Enabling LLDP and LACP, and verifying the connectivity between devices, would be good next steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your comments. The original topology has two routers and two Nexus switches where I wanted to enable features like VRRP on the L3 level and vPC on L2 among others. However, as issues on both layers started piling up, I downsized features and connections until I came with the a poin-to-point issue that triggered this post.

But as Jeff noted, the Po1 had two members because I forgot to shutdown the connection to the second Nexus switch, so once I turned it down pings were successful.

At this point I guess it's time for me to go back to the drawing board and review all settings. But now I had connectivity between the router and the switch.

Thanks again!